# SQL count for each day

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Is it possible to get in one shot a count(*) for each day of the last 15 days like I get for one day:

```
SELECT count(*) as total from users where `user_date_accountcreated` BETWEEN '2016-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-03 23:59:59'
```

To avoid making one SQL request per day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use mysql's date functions:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE u_d_a_c BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND now()
GROUP BY year(u_d_a_c), month(u_d_a_c), day(u_d_a_c)
```

Comment: Any reason why you didn't do "GROUP BY date(u_d_a_c)"?

Comment: I tested `SELECT COUNT(*) as total 
WHERE user_date_accountcreated BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND now() 
GROUP BY year(user_date_accountcreated), month(user_date_accountcreated), day(user_date_accountcreated)` and I have an error, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; near WHERE

Comment: Yes, thanks @MarcB and I added `SELECT date_format("user_date_accountcreated", "%Y-%m-%d")` as date as suggested by @Chris

Comment: if user_date_accountcreated is a date/datetime field, then don't format it like that. it's ALREADY in that format. if it's datetime, and you want to strip off the time component, then a simple `date(u_d_a_c)` does that for you, without forcing a full-blowin type-conversion/formatting run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(user_date_accountcreated, '%Y-%m-%d'), count(*) AS total

    FROM users 

  WHERE

    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), user_date_accountcreated) BETWEEN 1 AND 15

      GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(user_date_accountcreated, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy way is to group by date:

```
SELECT date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%y%m%d"), count(*) as total from users 
where `user_date_accountcreated` BETWEEN '2016-09-18 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-03 23:59:59'
GROUP BY date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%y%m%d")
```

Comment: Yes thanks that's a good idea to add as well the add the date_format() in the select.